# How to build the java project target as 1.5 by 1.6 JDK with Intellij IDEA?

Tags: jakarta-ee, intellij-idea

I am working on a project which must be deploy in the 1.5 runtime environment. So does anyone know how to build the project target as 1.5 by 1.6 JDK with Intellij IDEA, and My development is Mac OSX 10.8 and JDK 1.6

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bytecode version can be controlled per project or per module:

[image: bytecode version]

Comment: I tried,but still failed with this error: java: javacTask: source release 1.6 requires target release 1.6

Comment: Make sure project/[modules](http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/5387/20130511123324.png) [language level is set to 5.0](http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/6286/20130511123253.png) and Additional command line parameters field is empty.

Comment: I'm building a backend and wanted to change the language level on android studio 1.0 for my module to 1.7 java. I tried to change it in the above window but it doesn't seem to recognise my module at all so I could not use the per module bytecode version tool as displayed in your screen shot. Eventually, i solved this issue by typing in the line: List<String> string = new ArrayList<>(); The compiler picked up the error as the Language level set is incorrect and if you ALT+ENTER on the <>, you will be able to change your language level.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and I fixed it changing the maven compiler plugin configuration

```
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: If this is a Maven-based project, then this is the answer, because the other language level changes described above to the IntelliJ project settings will be lost if the Maven project is reimported.  Maven's default value for both of these properties is 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change this on an individual project basis, rather than setting the default bytecode version in the global settings.

In 2016.2:
File -> Project Structure
Under "Project Settings" -> Modules
Select the module to change in the left pane
Under "Sources" tab change the "Language level:" to any level supported by your JDK

[image: Select JDK bytecode version in 2016.2]